# How to resolve permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am writing a simple recipe to create file like:

```
file '/myfile' do
  content 'Welcome to Technical Guftgu'
  action :create
end
```

but on chef-client -zr "recipe[test::recipe1]"
i am getting the following error:

```
[2022-03-08T10:54:16+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2022-03-08T10:54:16+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
[2022-03-08T10:54:16+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/vagrant/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2022-03-08T10:54:16+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2022-03-08T10:54:16+00:00] FATAL: Errno::EACCES: file[/myfile] (test::recipe1 line 7) had an error: Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /myfile
```

Comment: As the answer(s) point out, its a permissions issue. You are trying to create a file in root (`/`) directory. Does the user with which you are running `chef-client` have permission to create file in this path?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your app does not have access to the file `/myfile`.

Try this, to allow access to all: `sudo chmod a+rw /myfile`

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are not executing this as a root user, change it to root by typing sudo su then rerun the command, hopefully this will help.

I was facing the same issue and stuck for an hour, just did it and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

### Errno::EACCES Means "Permission Denied"

The Errno class is mapped to your system call errors at runtime. You can find this (confusingly) documented in:

- [SystemCallError#errno](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/SystemCallError.html#method-i-errno)
- [Errno](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/Errno.html)

In particular:

```rb
Errno.constants.include? :EACCES
#=> true
```

on most *nix sytems Errno::EACCES maps to the [libc error code](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) for "permission denied". Specifically:

```
Macro: int EACCES

    "Permission denied." The file permissions do not allow the attempted operation.
```

That generally means your #create action doesn't have permissions to read, write, or traverse the path to the file you are trying to manage, so you need to change your implementation (which you don't show in your original post) to ensure that your Ruby process has the needed file or filesystem permissions to perform the requested operations.

### See Also

- [Understanding Ruby's strange "Errno" exceptions](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/understanding-rubys-strange-errno-exceptions/)
- [errno Lookup](https://www.errno.help/)
- `errno.h` from [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)