# permission @rb_sysopen error during install of the searchkick gem for my ruby on rails application

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, opensearch, searchkick

I am installing the searchkick gem to enable search capacilities on my application, but when running `brew services start opensearch` to start opensearch I get the following error: Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users//Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.opensearch.plist.

I have tried this line of code: `sudo chown -R "$*<My-Username>*":admin /Library/LaunchAgents/` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions)), but it did not work.

Could someone help me with this?
I am using a mac with an intel processor (i5)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chmod a+rw /Users/USERNAME/Library/LaunchAgents` fixed the issue for me!
[Source of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71393890/how-to-resolve-permission-denied-rb-sysopen)